# Why wasn't Adam Harishon given the Torah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torah-study, adam

If Adom Harishon was the purpose of the entire creation, why didn't Hashem give him the Torah?

We know that Hashem used the Torah as the blueprint for creation, so it seems strange it was not given to Adam.

Comment: the "Torah" and "giving" must be defined prior to answering this question. I assume you refer to the written scroll of Torah as we have nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

Adam was worthy of having the Torah given through him. Said the Holy One, Blessed is He “ I will give it to him for he is the work of my hands” After he sinned the Holy One, Blessed is He said to him “What Now? I gave you six commandments and you could not uphold them. How can I give you 613? Adam was worthy of begetting the twelve tribes. Said the Holy One Blessed is He “ I gave you two sons, and one rose and slew the other. What will happen if I give you twelve tribes? ([Bereishis Rabah 24:5](https://archive.org/stream/RabbaGenesis/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n249/mode/1up))

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, he was given the Torah. However, the Torah stayed oral and abstract and *could not* be limited to letters as we perceive the Torah after Matan Torah.

This could be compared to the 4 states of matter, in the beginning it was like fire, not even forming letters, then liquid, forming letters but not words and verses, and finally it was crystallized in the form of words and sentences as we know it.

Some say (*Beis Gnozay, p. Yisro*) that the Matan Torah in its literal form was caused by inability to complete the 400 years of slavery and the sin of the Golden calf, otherwise the Torah would stay oral, just the way our forefathers learned it.

Answer (score 0):

I heard someone mention that since he was created as full adult he could not be given the Torah. Only a child who grows with it can be worthy to accept it. I have not been able to find this said by anyone. Also is there a source for the idea Adom was created as a full grown adult? Is it a machloket?

Comment: Regarding your 2nd point (age) see Bereishis Rabah 14:7